# Does Minecraft PE support external keyboards?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can I control Minecraft Pocket edition with Logitech external keyboard?

Comment: Does the external keyboard work with other applications?

Comment: Yes, I can write but not control the game :(

Comment: I wonder should I change some settings or is it possible at all...

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried to move with the WASD keys - have you tried the arrow keys?

Comment: You should be able to do it with Bluetooth.

Answer (score 4):

**Sort of.**

You can use a Bluetooth keybord for signs, but there is currently no way to control the game. The ios text screen still comes up, but the Bluetooth keybord can control it. The only advantage is that you can type faster.